# java: programming against interface, but having to instantiate a concrete class

Tags: java, generics, interface

I'm giving my first steps with generics, and I've just coded a generic function to compare two List objects, like this

```
public static <T> List<T> diffAdded(List<T> source, List<T> dest) {
    List<T> ret = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(T element: dest) {
        if (!source.contains(element)) {
            ret.add(element);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Everything works fine, but I'm instantiating an ArrayList, because obviously I cannot instantiate an interface List

the fact is that I want to return an object of the same type as source...

how do you handle these kind of situations?

can I face any cast trouble with the method as it is right now?

thanks a lot

Comment: "*I want to return an object of the same type as source*" - why? You can obtain the real type of `source` using reflection and create an instance with reflection as well. But - why?

Comment: I see your point, good answer...

Comment: I agree with the "code smell" observation below.  However... if you really wanted to, you can add an instanceof check to source and instantiate a list of its specific type...  if( dest instanceof ArrayList) dest = new ArrayList<T>();  etc...

Comment: thanks, all the answers and the comments were quite helpful, it wasn't easy to decide which to choose...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question is *almost always* that "returning an object of the same type as the source" is not actually relevant to your application, and that you're going about things the wrong way.

If your caller needs a specific `List` implementation, because they'll be doing a specific kind of operation on it, then they can do the copying themselves...but if your method takes an arbitrary argument of type `List`, and the output changes semantically depending on the exact implementation of the input, then that's a huge code smell.

Leave your code as it is, and if your method's callers really, really need a specific implementation, then they can copy your output into that implementation themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two choices here.

1: Realize that the point of accepting the `List<T>` interface as your input type means that you are explicitly saying that you don't care about the underlying implementation.  Furthermore, by returning a `List<T>` it says that your caller shouldn't care about the underlying implementation either.  In most cases, a `List` is a `List` and the details shouldn't matter.  If it does, you should explicitly return `ArrayList<T>` instead.

2: Make a bunch of polymorphic calls that match every `List` implementation type that you want to support.

I very much think that the first answer is where you should direct your efforts.